# SQL Server 2019 Polybase error - cant create External Data Source to SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, polybase, sql-server-2019-express

I am trying to setup an external data source in SQL Server 2019 to another database on the same server.

I am doing this to replicate the SQL Azure setup currently running in production.

I tried the following to set it up

- I installed SQL Server 2019 Express
- I installed Polybase
- I enabled TCP/IP and made sure services were running

I then ran

```
USE master

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

EXEC sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;
RECONFIGURE;

USE mydb
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SqlServerCredentials
WITH IDENTITY = 'sa', SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SQLServerInstance
    WITH ( LOCATION = 'sqlserver://.\sqlexpress',
    PUSHDOWN = ON,
    CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials);
```

On the final CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE statement I get this error

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Cannot generate SSPI context".
> Msg -2146893042, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package

I can't seem to figure out why I get this error

Comment: I don't know what Polybase is, but the server that wrote you "Cannot generate SSPI contex" seems to be configured to windows authentication only, and you need to change it to mixed mode

Comment: You can find out authenticatio mode in the first rows of errorlog of your SQL Server. By default, if you don't change it, SQL Server is installed in Windows only authentication mode

Comment: Polybase is what allows external data sources in sql server.

Comment: This instance is set to mixed mode. I can login to management studio using the sql credentials "sa" and password

Comment: @MohamedCassim you can login to .\sqlexpress with the sa account? Just confirming which instance you verified was in mixed mode.

Comment: Yes, I only have a single instance installed, the .\sqlexpress instance. And I have tested the sa login is correct.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using Sql login. That should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer]. Why should "Sql login" work? Please [edit] your answer with more details.